# TextRenderer not displaying text

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, textrenderer

Following are implementation methods of `GLEventListener`
For some reason, no text is shown on screen?
The rest of my level objects draw fine. (with the exception of they all being tinted red)

```
private TextRenderer renderer;

public void init(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {

    GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    renderer = new TextRenderer(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 36));
}

public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    final GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

    if (height <= 0) { // avoid a divide by zero error!

        height = 1;
    }

    final float h = (float) width / (float) height;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(170.0f, h, 1.0, 20.0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {

    renderer.beginRendering(gLDrawable.getWidth(), gLDrawable.getHeight());
    renderer.setColor(1.0f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.8f);
    renderer.draw("Text to draw", 0, 0);
    renderer.endRendering();

    // draw squares, circles in the level etc       
    level.draw(gLDrawable);
}
```

Comment: By the way, that is one heck of a crazy FOV you have there; 340 degrees vertically. Humans can generally only see 135 degrees vertically (fovy = 67.5). What you have right now might be applicable for a deer or fish if it were ***horizontal*** FOV, but not a human with eyes both facing forward ;)

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is that you are probably clipping your text if it's at z=0. I would consider trying a plain old orthographic projection matrix when drawing your text, with z=-1 as zNear and z=1 as zFar. You cannot get much simpler than that, and it will place z=0 at the exact middle of your depth range. Something to this effect: `glOrtho (0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);` if you expect the point (0,0) to be the top-left corner of your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` inside `level.draw()`
Once I moved this before my text rendering, I could see it fine.
@Andon, I'll take your other points into consideration about fov